# How to Disable Alert pop-up while opening desktop application from browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, windows, desktop-application

How to Disable Alert pop-up while opening desktop application from browser. for example after typing calculator:// in browser we need to disable the alert box with the help of angular typescript file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZwWa.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature. You can disable it but it has to be done by the user. If this was something that could be disabled by the app then a malicious site could just disable before performing some kind of attach.

[Check out this discussion here](https://superuser.com/questions/1481851/disable-chrome-to-ask-for-confirmation-to-open-external-application-everytime)